# Trace zero not needed for $H^2$ regularity if $V_N\subset H^2$ is finite dim?

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory, finite-element-method

Reading Evans and [this note](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.09f/527_2009_lec19.pdf) after asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371181/delta-u-is-bounded-can-we-say-u-in-c1/), I have been thinking about the estimates for interior/global regularity in Evans, 6.3.1, theorem 1, and thoerem 4 in 6.3.2, of the form
$$\|u\|_{H^2(V)}\le C(\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\|u\|_{L^2(U)})$$
and
$$\|u\|_{H^2(U)}\le C(\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\|u\|_{L^2(U)})$$
Sadly, it seems in the first estimate general $V(\subset\subset U)$ cannot go to up the boundary without the trase zero condition, as the [note above](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.09f/527_2009_lec19.pdf) or
[Why does Boundary $H^2$ regularity fail for trace non-zero functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788315/why-does-boundary-h2-regularity-fail-for-trace-non-zero-functions) says.

But the counterexample by @levap in the above question makes me wonder if it is possible to get (not the fact that $\|u\|_{H^2(U)}$ is bounded itself, but) the global regularity inequality of the form above without the trace zero condition for elements of a finite dimensional subspace $X_N\subset H^2(U)$. Here, elements of $X_N$ do not necessarily vanish on the boundary. The boundary can be really smooth if that is needed.

The following is a motivation if you are interested:
If this type of estimate is available it would be convenient for analysing approximation methods such as the finite element method. For example, try to approximate the solution of $-\Delta u =f$ in $\Omega$ with $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ with the finite element method with hat function, say (further smoothness of functions can be assumed). Suppose $\Omega$ is not polygon. Then, in general approximation space $X_N={\rm span}\{\text{spanned by hat functions}\}$ is not a subspace of the solution space $H^{\text{some order}}_0(\Omega)$, since $v\in X_N$ does not vanish on the boundary, but takes zeros only on the nodes on the boundary. This makes analysis tedious, as the error $u-u_N$ does not vanish on the boundary. (Googling "variational crime" will show you details.) If we have the above estimate for $H^2_0\cup X_N$, that would be super.

I haven't a clue where to start by the way...

Comment: On a finite dimensional subspace you even have $\|u\|_{H^2}\le C\|u\|_{L^2}$, just by the compactness of the unit ball. But the constant $C$ depends on the subspace, and I'm pretty sure such an inequality isn't really useful for anything.

Comment: @NormalHuman As in $C=C(N)$ might grow with $N$ etc.? Hm. Ok. Thank you!